# Recursion-Printing Parents and Children with indentation(haml)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, recursion

I am trying to print parents' and children's name with indentation. But I am not sure how I can do that in the view.(haml)

I have a model with self join:(just to give you the structure, I also have other attributes etc. but I think they are irrelevant)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children,  :class_name => "Post"
  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => "Post", :foreign_key => "post_id"
end
```

So it has a hierarchy and I wanna have something like this(let's assume with the attribute 'name'):

```
Post 1
      Post 1.1
      Post 1.2
Post 2
      Post 2.1
              Post 2.2
```

I am pretty new in Ruby-on-rails. So please bear with me. I would really really appreciate if I could get a quite explanatory answer.

Thank you so much in advance,
J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use recursion.  create a partial that calls itself.

```
# app/views/posts/_post.html.haml
= post.title
= post.content
= render partial: 'post', collection: post.children
```

I'm assuming that you have a posts controller which comes with a folder for it's views in `app/views/posts`.  You need to create a partial there called `_post.html.haml` which calls
itself.  The `render` line tells you to render the same partial for each of the post's children.

the indentation can be handled via css.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I think the syntax is not really correct, it helped me to give an idea of how to do the recursion. Now I can iterate each item, but how can I indent without CSS?

Comment: i don't get what you mean by indent without CSS. the code above is a valid haml code (except the comment).

Comment: Well, I think you are missing the "=>"s. So "partial: 'post', :collection=> post.children, as => :post" . Thanks anyways. I think I will start a new question for the indentation part.

Comment: nope. that's the 1.9.x syntax for hash :) you also don't need the `:as` option since the name of the partial is `_post` and by convention, uses that as the local variable name.